# Understanding consumeRollupEvent

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, mouseevent

I have an add-on, where when user holds down right mouse button, they can scroll the wheel and it will change tabs.

Now in Windows, if user pushes down on right button it doesn't open context menu. In linux it opens context menu on mouse down.

`DOMMouseScroll` event listner is on the chrome window ie: `window.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', func, true)`

So if you copy this code and paste it to scratchapd:

```
window.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', function() {
  window.removeEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', arguments.callee, true);
  console.log('scroll caught and removed')
}, true)
```

then go to the browser window, right click to open context menu, and scroll while mouse is over the context-menu, in windows, the scroll is caught. In linux it is not. (curious note here: mousedown events are caught if listener added on window and the click was in the context-menu).

I thought setting consume rollup event to no consume would solve it. But it's not.

Any ideas on how to fix this issue and does consumeRollupEvent have any affect here?

Currently i was setting consume rollup event to false in the `popupshowing` event of context-menu:

```
noConsume: function(event)  {
    if (event.target != document.getElementById('contentAreaContextMenu')) { return }
    if (event.target.popupBoxObject)    {
        //event.target.popupBoxObject.setConsumeRollupEvent(Components.interfaces.nsIPopupBoxObject.ROLLUP_NO_CONSUME); //no longer support setConsumeRollupEvent
    }
        event.target.setAttribute('consumeoutsideclicks', false);
        event.target.consumeoutsideclicks = false;
},
```

Right now I'm suspecting it's the `DOMMouseScroll` event that's not being caught, so i changed it to `addEventListner('wheel'...` and sent user test addon, waiting for his word back.

Comment: I *really* don't understand your question/questions? Is it about `DOMScrollEvent`? `setConsumeRollupEvent`? What's your actual question? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: forgive me i tend to ramble :P thx so much for asking for clarification and patience. Im trying to make the `window.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll'...` work right even if mouse is hovered over context menu. I thought `consumeoutsideclicks`/`setConsumeRollupEvent` was the solution, I don't think it is, could you please help understand why even when i set consume rollup events to false that the wheel event is not triggering on window while scroll of wheel is done while hovered over context menu.

Comment: @nmaier my bug here explains it a bit more: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1037048 we think it's a bug

Answer (score 2):

I don't think setConsumeRollupEvent will help you to intercept the scroll events. It refers to the rolling up of the context menu (i.e. the event that caused the context menu to close); nothing to do with mouse wheel rolling.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Method/setConsumeRollupEvent

It might be worth concentrating on why there is a difference in behaviour between Windows and Linux. It might be a Firefox bug or at the very least it might give you a clue about the best way to work around it. Maybe there is a way to prevent the context menu being invoked on MouseDown in Linux, it sounds like that would be the most desirable outcome for your add-on.